# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

When i run the below code :

```
input("请输入1—100之间的数字：")
n = input
if n >= 1 and n <= 100:
    print("你妹好漂亮！")
else:
    print("你大爷好丑")
print("游戏结束啦！不和你玩了")


if n >= 1 and n <= 100:
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of
>   'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Comment: First, merge the first two lines, i.e. `n = input("...")`. Second, read a Python introductory tutorial before writing any code.

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake 1:**
You need to store the `input()` value in a *container/variable*.  Which is why you get your error in the first hand.

**Mistake 2:**
Also looks like you are asking the user for an integer input, in which case you need to convert the default `string` type to `int()`

Below code is fixed version for your scenario.

```
n = int(input("请输入1—100之间的数字："))
if n >= 1 and n <= 100:
    print("你妹好漂亮！")
else:
    print("你大爷好丑")
print("游戏结束啦！不和你玩了")


if n >= 1 and n <= 100:
   #Your if logic goes here.
```